# Where can I find C# code for console application designs. The star pyramid for example

Tags: c#, c++

I want to know if there's a website that provides code star designs for my console application. For example I want a code that can output the pyramid using for loops:

```
    *
   ***
  *****
*********
```

Or code that can output the half-life logo using for loops.
It doesn't matter where the code was created, as long as I can understand the for loop it is ok.

Comment: Why don't you just open up C# and play around with the for loop? You'll understand better by playing with it instead of downloading the source code for your homework ;-)

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/392788/ - Okay, it's for christmas trees, but just leave out the stump and you're fine.

Comment: I've had this question on a C exam 17 years ago...

Comment: Yeah, it's part of my homework. I can do the pyramid and some simple stuffs but I discovered that you can do some complex stuff with the for loop. And I want to find out more about it, I want to know how complex the design can get with the for loops and I want to study it by myself by looking at them.

Comment: Consider talking with your classmates, peers, and professors on this: an algorithms, or any CS class for that matter, is best experienced by getting dirty :-)

Comment: C++ tag? I'm pretty sure this is just C#... Damn you contaminating my RSS feeds ;)

Answer (score 2):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

namespace Pyramid
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                Console.Write("Enter the Height of the Pyramid: ");
                int n = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
                {
                    for (int j = n; j >= i; j--)
                    {
                        Console.Write(" ");
                    }
                    for (int k = 1; k <= i; k++)
                    {
                        Console.Write("*");
                    }
                    for (int m = 2; m <= i; m++)
                    {
                        Console.Write("*");
                    }
                    Console.WriteLine();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            } Console.Read();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
int height = 5;

for (int count = 1; count <= height; count++)
    Console.WriteLine(new String('*', count * 2 - 1).PadLeft(height + count));
```

Comment: You should use Environment.NewLine instead of the string literal "\r\n". :) (It's one of those little things many people don't realize exists.)

Answer (score 1):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace PyramidUsingForLoops
{
    class StarPyramid
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int Row = 5;
            for (int i = 0; i < Row; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < Row-(i+1); j++)
                {
                    Console.Write(" ");
                }
                for (int k = 0; k < 2*i+1; k++)
                {
                     Console.Write("*");
                }
                Console.WriteLine();

            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
namespace Program
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // print triangle
            int n = 5;
            /* three phrase: 
             * first: find first location of the line
             * second: print increasing
             * third: print decreasing */
            int k=n;
            for (int i = 0; i <n; i++)  //print n line
            {
                //  first
                for (int j = 1; j <= k; j++) Console.Write(" ");
                // second
                for (int j = 1; j <= i; j++) Console.Write(j);
                // third
                for (int j = i + 1; j >= 1; j--) Console.Write(j);
                k--;
                Console.WriteLine();
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int rowCount = 5;
for (int i = 0; i < rowCount; i++)
{
    Console.Write(new string(' ', rowCount - i - 1));
    Console.Write(new string('*', 2 * i + 1));
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your comment to the question: you're saying that one can do "some complex stuff" with the `for`-loop you're trying to discover. I have to say: you seem to be on the wrong track. The `for`-loop has always the same simple structure:

```
for (Type variable = startvalue; condition; action)
{
    // Do stuff
}
```

The "complex" stuff is to sometimes find out what condition is or what action to take. `condition` may be *anything* that evaluates to `boolean` and `action` may be anything too.

So the "complex" stuff has nothing to do with the structure of the `for`-loop itself. You could also write the following:

```
for (int i = 0; DateTime.Now < new DateTime(2009, 12, 31); i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine("I've iterated {0} times before 31st December 2009!", i);
}
```

The condition does not even consider the `i` variable, but still it is a valid `for`-loop.